# Spring Boot how to configure list of Hikari datasources dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, hikaricp

If I only have one datasource and I want to configure it with Hikari then in `application.yml` I can do something like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    app:
      platform: POSTGRESQL
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
      username: mydbuser
      password: mydbpass
      hikari:
        maximum-pool-size: 15
        leak-detection-threshold: 15000
        max-lifetime: 900000
        data-source-properties: stringtype=unspecified
        pool-name: defaultHikariPool
```

And in code I do this:

```
  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.app")
  fun appDataSourceProperties(): DataSourceProperties {
    return DataSourceProperties()
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.app.hikari")
  fun appDataSource(): HikariDataSource {
    return appDataSourceProperties()
      .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
      .type(HikariDataSource::class.java)
      .build()
  }
```

This works very well. But let's say I have N datasources where size of N can vary depending on deployment. I created a block like this in the `applicaiton.yml`:

```
my-custom-parties:
  parties:
    - my-custom-party-id: 1
      datasource:
        platform: POSTGRESQL
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db-1
        username: user1
        password: pass1
        hikari:
          pool-name: db1HikariPool
          maximum-pool-size: 3
          leak-detection-threshold: 5000
          max-lifetime: 900000
          data-source-properties: stringtype=unspecified
    - my-custom-party-id: 2
      datasource:
        platform: POSTGRESQL
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db-2
        username: user2
        password: pass2
        hikari:
          pool-name: db2HikariPool
          maximum-pool-size: 10
          leak-detection-threshold: 20000
          max-lifetime: 900000
          data-source-properties: stringtype=unspecified
```

And I created a configuration class like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-custom-parties")
class MyCustomParties {
  private var parties: List<MyCustomParty> = listOf()

  fun setParties(parties: List<MyCustomParty>) {
    this.parties = parties
  }

  fun getParties() = parties
}

class MyCustomParty {
  lateinit var myCustomPartyId: String
  private var datasource: DataSourceProperties? = null

  fun setDatasource(datasource: DataSourceProperties) {
    this.datasource = datasource
  }

  fun getDatasource() = datasource?.initializeDataSourceBuilder()?.type(HikariDataSource::class.java)?.build()
}
```

This intializes a hikari datasource, but it doesn't pick up the configuration properties from the file.

I can't hardcode `@Bean`'s for every datasource because the number of datasources is different in different deployments.

**So how can I wire this together correctly?**